# C/C++ on Arduino string .replace() function is not working

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have this method in Arduino which has its programming language based on C/C++ and it is supposed to replace \r and \n so that it prints \r and \n as it is, but when I try to run the code it gives an no match for operator error:

```
void debugmsg(String msgtext) {
  msgtext = msgtext.replace("\r","\\r");
  msgtext = msgtext.replace("\n","\\n");
  Serial.println(msgtext1 + "\r\n");
}
```

> no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'void')

i dont know what's wrong, thank you for helping!

Comment: The replace function is most probably not returning the string but modify it directly ... just a guess ...

Comment: The reference https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringReplace however states: "replace ... Returns another String containing the new string with replaced characters."

Comment: @PeterG. The documentation is ... less than awesome in many places. Notice that the provided [example code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringReplace) does not deal with any return values.

Comment: @BoBTFish No, I see that too. OK, I have no idea what's going on. They don't publish the freaking prototype in the docs, bleh.

Comment: I think I found it, [here is the relevant `WString` header](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/9492d5ee058d455c88ee725f4b35fbb403cc1d2d/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.h#L181). The `replace()` methods are `void`.

Comment: @unw I don't know what the hell is going on but Arduino must sort their stuff together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.Replace()` is a void function. It modifies the string directly so no need to assign it to anything. Just use it like below and it WILL replace it:

```
msgtext.replace("\r","\\r");
msgtext.replace("\n","\\n");
```

The `replace()` from Arduino is a different function than the one you are using here because here it is C/C++ programming language. That one does return a `String`

**Edit:**

As @unwind noticed, the [**Arduino Documentation**](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringReplace) states that `replace()` returns a String. However, the Syntax part AND in their example code [**HERE**](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringReplace), it shows a routine usage of that function which is modifying the string directly and not returning a `String` ! I don't know. Anyway just use it as my above code.

Comment: @ra glad we helped